# Edges showing in texture

Tags: uv, edges

I've been unwrapping using *Reset* to save space on my UVs when using simple materials.

[image]

I've scaled down the unwrapped sections thinking maybe it was hitting the edges of the colour but it hasn't made any difference.

[image]

Looks fine in Blender but when I take it to Sketchfab, Unity or Unreal I get edge lines on my textures (only seems to show at certain zoom levels in viewports but shows on all renders).

[image]

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Mesh is auto smoothed and normals facing correctly. I know this is technically an issue outside Blender but it's something I'm doing wrong in Blender in the first place.

Comment: This is most likely an issue in sketchfab than

Comment: Thanks, it also happens in Unreal. I'll keep hacking away at it.

Comment: Even if it happens in both Sketchfab and Unreal, I don't think it's a problem in Blender since it works fine there. Maybe the other softwares don't like those stacked UV faces? But since this is a Blender site I'm afraid I don't know anything about that in the other software. I know from Imphenzia's low poly modeling tutorials that he's using color palettes and scales the UVs down to zero and moves the points to color the parts. But I think he says in one of his videos that Unreal or Unity (don't remember) doesn't like UVs with zero size so for this software he has to slightly scale them up.